# pixel values changing after doing imwrite in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

The imwrite function is behaving in a weird way. I have modified a single pixel value of an image. After performing imwrite, however, the pixel value is either getting changed to a entirely new value OR is remaining unchanged.

```
function imwriteCheck(input_image,output_image)
a=imread(input_image);
fprintf('\nBefore modification a(1,1,1)=%d\n',a(1,1,1));
a(1,1,1)=50;
fprintf('\nAfter modification a(1,1,1)=%d\n',a(1,1,1));
imwrite(a,output_image);
b=imread(output_image);
fprintf('\nValue at b(1,1,1)=%d\n',b(1,1,1));
end
```

I've tested this function with two images and the outputs are as follows:

```
>> imwriteCheck('MOM.jpg','MOMout.jpg')

Before modification a(1,1,1)=206

After modification a(1,1,1)=50

Value at b(1,1,1)=170

>> imwriteCheck('durga.jpg','durgaout.jpg')

Before modification a(1,1,1)=63

After modification a(1,1,1)=50

Value at b(1,1,1)=63
```

I cannot understand why this is happening. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you write to a jpg file, pixel values get changed because of their lossy compression technique. you can write to a jpg file using lossless mode but then you wont be able to view the image anywhere else. 
try writing to a bmp or png file, you'll see the pixel values are NOT changing.